# Gabor Filter c++(OpenCv) :error

Tags: c++, opencv, gabor-filter

the code :

```
   for (int j = 0; j<4; j++)    
    {
    int kernel_size = 3;
        Mat dest;
         double sig = 5, th = 0, lm = 8, gm = 0.02, ps = 0;
      cv::Mat kernel = cv::getGaborKernel(cv::Size(kernel_size,kernel_size), sig, theta[j], lm, gm, ps, CV_32F);
        filter2D(src_f, dest, CV_32F, kernel);
        destArray.push_back(dest);              
    }
```

the error getGaborKerbel is not a member of cv :(

```
    37  28  F:\main.cpp [Error] 'getGaborKernel' is not a member of 'cv'
```

Comment: Can we see the code snippet? stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Don't share code in external links - future readers will find this post useless if the link goes dead.  And make the effort to complete the 2-minute site tour as well.

Comment: Post code here! and remember that it has to be Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example please! http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Guys is Clear now ?

Comment: Did you included imgproc?

Comment: ues i included it -- #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and looking for a solutions I found I must include the

> imgproc library

as follows:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
```

Regards.